# Clarinet range-transposing a cello part

Tags: transposition, cello, clarinet

I have a cello part that I would like to transpose for clarinet. The lowest note is a concert G(2 below middle C). Is there a clarinet that has that note?

Comment: Unless you need to match the exact pitches (say you're replacing the cello in some chamber ensemble),  consider transposing from Concert Pitch to Bb, and moving up a couple octaves into normal clarinet range.  Alto and Bass clarinets sound significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great web page that has the ranges of almost all orchestral instruments:

http://www.orchestralibrary.com/reftables/rang.html

Answer (score 0):

There are in fact a few clarinets that can play as low as G2. However, the most commonly used of these is the Bass Clarinet in Bb, which sounds an octave lower than the most common clarinet, the Clarinet in Bb.

The Basset Horn and Alto Clarinet can also play G2, but are far less commonly owned or played. And of course, G2 is relatively “mid-range” for Contrabass Clarinet, which once again would be considered a rarely used instrument.